# Enable antialiasing in Opengl ES 2 (ios)

Tags: c++, ios, opengl-es, antialiasing, multisampling

i'm having issues enabling multisampling in IOS.

I'm referring to this [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithEAGLContexts/WorkingwithEAGLContexts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH103-SW12)

If you scroll down to

Listing 4-5  Creating the multisample buffer

You can see it clearly state we need (of course) a resolve buffer. However, it doesn't show any kind of initialization in the first step. Do i just need to

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &resolveBuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, resolveBuffer);
```

when should i initialize my frame buffer object?

Also, last step is not clear to me.

```
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderbuffer);
[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
```

where exactly should i do this? and what does it accomplish? I guess after the draw calls from my fbo and vbo but i'm not really sure.

Has anyone a link to some kind of example project i can look up? i googled but i can't find any :(

Lastly, i'm using float textures to render HDR images. Do i have to keep GL_RGBA8_OES in this instruction?

```
glRenderbufferStorageMultisampleAPPLE(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 4, GL_RGBA8_OES, width, height);
```

it's not really clear to me if at this point i've already rendered to a texture.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You use the same code as when you don't use multi-sampling. Then you add an extra frame buffer using multi-sampling on its render buffer `glRenderbufferStorageMultisampleAPPLE(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 4, GL_RGBA8_OES, width, height)` When drawing you need to have the sample buffer bound instead of the original one. When you are done drawing you need to resolve the sample buffer to your original buffer:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER_APPLE, originalFrameBuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER_APPLE, sampleFrameBuffer);
glResolveMultisampleFramebufferAPPLE();
```

At this point you have filled the original buffer (`originalFrameBuffer`) and you may use it any way you please, you may even bind it and continue drawing to it, use it as a texture or as in apple example present its render buffer content onto the view.